# Kubernetes Redirecting echo into a file not creating file

Tags: kubernetes

My goal is to write a simple init pod to echo something into a file using a redirect (`>`) for testing purposes but instead, printing the redirect and file name.  Here's the relevant part of my yaml:

```
  initContainers:
  - name: cat-to-file
    image: alpine
    args: [ "echo", "Hello, World", ">", "test"]
    workingDir: /project
    volumeMounts:
    - name: project-files
      mountPath: /project
```

But, the file doesn't get created and when I view the container logs via:

```
kubectl logs <pod id> cat-to-file
```

It shows me:

```
Hello, World, > test
```

Which makes me think it's echoing the `> test` to stdout rather than to a file named `test`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
...
args: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello World > test"]
...
```

This approach worked for me [here](https://github.com/radanalyticsio/spark-operator/blob/9b6a08811738e0b10b6c2dd95578fd9a33cbecf0/src/main/java/io/radanalytics/operator/cluster/KubernetesSparkClusterDeployer.java#L230).

Comment: This works.  Would you mind explaining why my way doesn't though?

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't have syntax for implicitly wrapping things in a shell, the way Dockerfiles or `docker-compose.yml` do; your `args:` are passed as literally the arguments without interpolation beyond known environment variable expansion.  The Kubernetes docs have [a similar example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#run-a-command-in-a-shell).

Comment: So using `command: ["/bin/sh"]` and `args: ["-c", "echo Hello World > test "]` also works.